# How do I make a shortcut to open local repo via Git GUI?

Tags: git, git-gui

I already found some time ago the way to create shortcut to open local repository via Git bash. I would just add `--cd="C:\RepoFolder"` in shortcut properties -> Target after exe path.
But the same approach didn't work with Git GUI.
So is there a way to do the same? Just create a shortcut which would open local repository in Git GUI and no additional clicks needed?

Comment: You can modify the `Start in` field (just below `Target` field) in the shortcut's properties to point to the repo folder, by default it is `%HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH%`, you can replace it with this `%HOMEDRIVE%\RepoFolder`

Comment: @SaurabhPBhandari, thanks. Yes, that worked. Why didn't you write it as the answer to the question?

Comment: Mainly because the question is off-topic here. Such questions are on topic [here](https://superuser.com)